# n-th root of a number

Tags: c++, input, root

I am trying to write a program (c++ console application) that calculates the n-th root of a number, where the n and the number are input from keyboard, but I don't know how (sorry for bad English). Can someone please write this program for me so I can see how it's done. Btw I'm new to programing so please make it as simple as possible. Thanks

Comment: That is what books, tutorials, and classes are for (not this site).

Comment: An algorithm to calculate this can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm). Try coding it and see what you get. If you run into any issues, come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking members of the site to write a program. SO is not a freelancer site providing services for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I think

```
double NthRoot(double value, double degree)
{
    return pow(value, (double)(1 / degree));
}
```

From [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root#C.2B.2B).